# python subprocess.run() timeout option fails to kill a MS Access app

Tags: python-3.x, batch-file, ms-access, subprocess

My python script executes a .bat fie which in turn runs a Microsoft (MS) Access program. The MS Access app populates the DB then quits. Sometimes Access fails due a corrupt DB or whatever issue that may cause it to hang. I want to avoid this and kill the process if it runs longer than some seconds variable.  Testing my script I set timeout=5 (seconds) for a process that takes at least 10 seconds.  When the timeout fires it waits. It doesn’t kill the process but instead waits until the MS Access process completes (as per the subprocess.run python docs).  How can I kill the MS Access app. The code works as expected for bat files that don’t call Access.

```
    if( args.verbose ):
        print( "Starting timer for " + str( alarmTime ) + " mintues" )

    try:
        proc = subprocess.run( [ batchFile ],
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
            universal_newlines=True,
            shell=False,
            check=True,
            timeout=5 )
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        if( args.verbose ):
            print ( "FAIL: Ran batch: ", batchFile, " and it timed out!" )

        if( args.email ):
            email( "FAIL: A batch script process is running longer than 15 minutes\nSomething is wrong\nquitting", mailTo )

        returnStatus = returnStatus + " The following batch job timed out: " + batchFile + "\n"

        dependancy[ batchFile ][ 1 ] = None

        continue

    dependancy[ batchFile ][ 1 ] = RunStatus( True, ( True if proc.returncode == 0 else False ) )

    if( proc.returncode != 0 ):
        returnStatus = returnStatus + " The following batch job failed: " + batchFile + "\n"
```

Comment: Why use the batch file just to launch Access? Why don't you run Access directly from your Python script?

Comment: @Squashman is right.  You'll have better control, with less effort, if the Access is the child process of your python session, than if it's a grand-child process.

Comment: Yup, @Squashman is correct. When I removed calling access from a bat file and called it directly I was able to kill the running MS Access application when the timeout fired.  Thanks!